# Lightning Component retrieving text value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I've been working with a Lightning component that has me confounded. I have found a workaround for this issue temporarily, but I'd really like to figure out what is wrong here.

Here is the component markup in question:

```
<aura:component controller='ControllerHere' implements='flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId' access='global'>

  <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selUserType" multiple="false" class='userTypeSel' value='{!v.selUserType}'>
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Example1" label="Internal"/>
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Example2" label="External"/>
  </ui:inputSelect>

  <ui:inputText class='filter' aura:id='filterFieldName' placeholder='{!v.filterFieldName}' value='{!v.filter}' keyup='{!c.updateUsers}'/>
</aura:component>
```

The goal here is to filter a list of objects by typing into the `ui:inputText`. Now, getting the value of the selected option of the select list, works as expected using:

```
component.find('selUserType').get('v.value');
component.get('v.selUserType'); // this also works
```

The problem I'm having is retrieving the value of the `ui:inputText` element. Trying the same method used in retrieving the select list value is not working for me.

e.g.

```
 component.find('filterFieldName').get('v.value'); // undefined
 component.find('filterFieldName').get('v.text'); // undefined
 component.find('filterFieldName').get('v.class'); // 'filter'
 component.find('filterFieldName').get('v.required') // false

 component.get('v.filter'); // undefined
```

The `class` attribute returns the correct class, however, all I need is the text the user typed. According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm), I believe this method should work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've also found this [link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/input/input.cmp) and this [one](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputBaseOption/inputBaseOption.intf) which I'm assuming are the valid attributes for an input element within the framework. Any insight/nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

As a note, the workaround I mentioned above was to use a standard html input element as opposed to a `ui:inputText`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the updateOn attribute. The default is change, but you action is being called on keyUp wich is before. You need to add the `updateOn="keyup"` attributte to your input text.

```
<ui:inputText class='filter' aura:id='filterFieldName' placeholder='{!v.filterFieldName}' value='{!v.filter}' keyup='{!c.updateUsers}' updateOn="keyup"/>
```